# Trim nonempty rows using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using below code to trim data in column A, but its giving me defined error. Can someone help me on this.

```
Sub RemoveLeadingSpace()

Dim spem As Workbook
Dim calc As Worksheet

Set spem = Excel.Workbooks("Sw.xlsm")
Set calc = spem.Worksheets("calc")

spem.Worksheets("calc").Activate

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
For i = 1 To LR
    With calc.Range("A" & i)
        calc.Range("A" & i).Value = Trim(calc.Range("A" & i).Value)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact error and on which line?

Comment: On calc.Range("A" & i).Value = Trim(calc.Range("A" & i).Value). Error is Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Does your column contain any error values?

Comment: I think there was something. Added "On Error Resume Next" and it worked as expected. Thanks you.

Comment: On Error Resume Next is not really a good solution. Debug your error. You said you have it on line `calc.Range("A" & i).Value = Trim(calc.Range("A" & i).Value)`. What is the value of `i` in that moment? what is the value of `Range("Ai")` when error appears?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this would be to check whether the cell in question contains an error, something like below, also the line with `spem.Worksheets("calc").Activate` is not needed.

```
Sub RemoveLeadingSpace()
Dim spem As Workbook: Set spem = Excel.Workbooks("Sw.xlsm")
Dim calc As Worksheet: Set calc = spem.Worksheets("calc")
'above declare and set you workbook and worksheet
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data

For i = 1 To LR 'loop from row 1 to last
    If Not IsError(calc.Range("A" & i).Value) Then 'check if cell contains error
        calc.Range("A" & i).Value = Trim(calc.Range("A" & i).Value) 
        'if no error, then trim
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Small Addition: `Debug.Print "Error in row " & i, CStr(calc.Range("A" & i).Value)` might even throw sort of error description, e.g. *"Error 2007"* if a `DIV/#0!` error occured.